# stuff viewmodel into html.actionlink

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to stuff my ViewModel into an Ajax.ActionLink?

**edit** I'd like to take my 5 search fields on my page which are bind to a view model and send it along my .ActionLink as my object value parameter.

Thanks,
rod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `Ajax.ActionLink`, can't you use a normal submit button inside your form? You could even style it as a link if you use `<input type="image" ...`. This way when the user clicks on the button it will submit the whole form together with the search values. Then ajaxify the form with `Ajax.BeginForm`.

To avoid polluting your markup with javascript, I would strongly recommend you using the more unobtrusive jQuery framework instead of Microsoft Ajax.

Comment: Currently the form is posting back for the search page to retrieve results for a paged grid (Which doesn't have all the records for an export to Excel which is also an option on the page). The form I'm using is <% Ajax.BeginForm %> and I can't get the file download dialog for the export due to, I guess, the UpdateTargetId of the form. There in lies my issues.

Answer (score 0):

This will create a link with url parameters from your model:

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("Link Text", "View", "Controller", new { urlParam = Model.Param1, urlParam2 = Model.Param2}, new AjaxOptions() ) %>
```

Comment: But it won't account for changes the user might introduce in the search text fields once the view has been rendered.